# IronPython 2.7A1 execute from file source throws method not implemented error

Tags: c#, ironpython

I am trying to call a python script from a windows executable, ultimately the goal is a windows service that I can plug various scripts into, for example to pull back email attachments (since python has good imap support).  Of course, I am a total newb so I am clueless :)  I get an unhandled exception:

System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.  at Microsoft.Scripting.PlatformAdaptationLayer.OpenInputFileStream(String path)

and gobs more but that seems to be the key issue.  Clearly this must have to do with reading the code from a file because the simple change below makes it work.  I'm wondering if this is a bug in IP 2.7A1 but I think I would have found that in my *hopefully* exhaustive web search.  Okay, here's the code:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("PyTest.py");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
script.Execute(scope);
```

and the PyTest.py code is very simple, an example from the web:

```
import sys

#def Main():

def adder(arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 + arg2

class MyClass(object):
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
```

if I call that script by assigning it to a string value and using the CreateScriptSourceFromString method it works fine.  I have verified that the code can see the PyTest.py file by doing a file.exists(fileName) and it sees the file.  I also tried explicitly giving the path to no avail.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're using a build of IronPython which is for the .NET framework? The Silverlight builds (which will also load on the desktop framework) have filesystem stuff disabled. I can do this from a console .exe just fine, so please provide some more information.

Comment: You may be on to it, I did have to get the dlls from the Silverlight folder which bugged me a bit, that would explain it.  I have the 2.71A release from http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/42434 In the installer options I see bins under Silverlight but not under tools for VS.

Comment: In Alpha 1 we only installed the binaries into the GAC.  You can find those below %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly.  In 2.7B1 we now include the files in the install dir as well so it's more convenient to find them.

Comment: YES!!!!  thanks very much, that was the problem, also got rid of my mysterious warning.  Excellent!